# Making links in VimOrganizer visible (vimscript and colors)

Tags: colors, vim

VimOrganizer seems to work alright, except that all of the links are black text on a black screen. At least, I think they are -- I type them in using `[[wikiword brackets]]`, and then when move off the line, they can only be seen if I am visually highlighting them.

I'd figure I need to make an adjustment to [this file](https://github.com/hsitz/VimOrganizer/blob/master/ftplugin/org.vim), but I don't seen anything obvious that is setting links to black. So perhaps I'm up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't a color problem -- it was a compressing links problem. `<leader>lx` makes links "uncompressed", and hence visible.